# Making difference from unit test and real jar in code

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, unit-testing

I play around with spark session.
For a test, I need to make session in local standalone.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Csv Application")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")

SparkSession.builder
    .config(conf)
    .appName("spark session example")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///.")
    .getOrCreate()
```

In deploy mode, Spark session should be created like below.

```
SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("Spark Pi")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Because there is a gap, I need to change everytime when I do test and deploy.
Is there any way that eclipse or scala notify itself what type of enviroment it is currently?

Comment: May be you can leverage some environment variables which can be captured in your scala code and based on value you can change the creation of Spark Session?

Comment: You can use `before` and `after` blocks of `org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter`  for initializing and terminating `SparkSession` in your test cases.